# java Project with error in StringTokenizer

Tags: java

I made a java project that involves a StringTokenizer, I used the file FemaleCoursesElec.csv, that which is separated by a comma, then I used it to fill the array1 but there is a problem I don't know what its?

this was the class :

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package shakeelprojectmain;

/**
 *
 * @author lenovo
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
     
public class ArrayOfCourses {
    
    public String[][] getAllCourses() throws IOException
    {
        
     String[][] array1 = new String[getRow()][getCol()];   
      
     int i = 0; 
     String str;
    
    File file = new File("FemaleCoursesElec.csv");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
      
  while(in.hasNext())
  {

   str = in.nextLine();
   StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(str,",");
    
   while(token.hasMoreTokens())
   {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < getCol() ; j++)
    {
                                
     array1[i][j] = token.nextToken();

    }
   }
   i++;
  }                
    
        in.close();
      
     
     return array1;
    }
    
 
    /**
     *
     * @return
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public  int getRows() throws IOException 
    {
    int row = 0; 
    
    
    File file = new File("FemaleCoursesElec.csv");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    
    while(in.hasNext())
    {
     in.nextLine();
     row++;    
        
    }
    
        in.close();
        return row;
    
    }
    
    public int getCol() throws IOException
    {
        
        int col = 0; 
        File file = new File("FemaleCoursesElec.csv");
  Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
  String str = in.nextLine();
  StringTokenizer token;
        token = new StringTokenizer(str,"," );

  while(token.hasMoreTokens())
  {
   token.nextToken();
   col++;
  }

  in.close();
  return col;
    
    }

    private int getRow()  throws IOException 
    {
        
        int row = 0; 
        File file = new File("FemaleCoursesElec.csv");
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

  while(inputFile.hasNext())
  {
   inputFile.nextLine();
   row++;
  }
  
  inputFile.close();
  return row;
        
        
        
   
        
        
    }
    }
```

the Main Program is here :

```js
package shakeelprojectmain;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author lenovo
 */
public class ShakeelProjectMain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        ArrayOfCourses array11 = new ArrayOfCourses();
        String[][] array1 = array11.getAllCourses();
        
        System.out.println(array1[0][0]+"\n" + array1[0][2]);
        
    }
    
}
```

but every time I run this it appears there is a fault in StringTekonizer?

the fault shows this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
at shakeelprojectmain.ArrayOfCourses.getAllCourses(ArrayOfCourses.java:40)
at shakeelprojectmain.ShakeelProjectMain.main(ShakeelProjectMain.java:25)
```

I tried many times to solve this problem but I couldn't, how should I solve this?

Comment: From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code_

Comment: Is this a learning exercise with regards to the StringTokenizer, or is it your desire to process a CSV? There are better ways to do it.

Comment: tell me how to do it please, because i want the excel sheet saved in array and this the only way i know

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
        while(token.hasMoreTokens()) {
```

It is guaranteed to have at least one token.
But, here:

```
            for (int j = 0 ; j < getCol() ; j++) {
                array1[i][j] = token.nextToken();
```

you iterate through more than one.
You can only have one `nextToken()` call per `hasMoreTokens()`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but can you show me the suitable way to write it ?